# Cocos2d html5 vs Cocos2d-x in C++

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-html5

I´m trying develop a game multiplatform, and wondering about the pros and cons about use Cocos2d html5 in JS vs Cocos2d-x in pure C+.
Anyone have a feedback about use case for each technology?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Question like this tend to attract subjective answers and are off topic on SO.

Comment: This question have response and there are similars in this site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399341/cocos2d-for-iphone-vs-cocos2d-x. Please consider your comments, beatiful man.

Comment: Sometimes questions like this slip through the cracks. Generally the problem with x vs y questions is that they depend on specific requirements and programming language expertise more than anything. The SO help center denotes questions about "Product or service recommendations or comparisons" as off-topic. In this particular case it's not even a useful comparison to make, development in HTML5/JS is very different from C++ development.

Comment: Yes, but the objective is make an app with language and targets platforms, and I think is very import decision that you have to make when init a project. Insist this a valid and interesting question. For example that LearnCocos2D comments is the diferent language, ok HTML 5 and JS would be an more easy language, other pro is relationated about de diferents platfoms you can deploy (mobile, web browsers and desktop with browsers engines). And what about performance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour Ask practical, detailed questions. This question is attracting subjective opinions and it's too broad. Unless someone literally answers "anyone have some experience about this?" with "Yes". ;)

Comment: Thanks Learncocos2d. The question keep open.

Answer (score 2):

Cocos2d-x

pros: Cross platform native app, great performance

cons: coding in C++, not available on web

---

Cocos2d-html5

pros: Cross platform on WEB, possible to publish in native with JSB, easy to code and maintain

cons: WEB app's performance is limited

Comment: Cocos2d-x with emscripten could be compile to JS with ASM optimitation.

Comment: also, with Cocos2d-html5 all your code will be exposed, while if you use cocos2d-x without js everything will stay closed source after compilation...

Comment: Just exactly how is "coding in C++" a con, compared to JS, totally defeats my understanding